# Is it possible to use `ts-node-dev` to run a npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I like `ts-node-dev` and I'm trying to avoid adding `nodemon` as a dev-dependence.

Nodemon allows executing an arbitrary command on current path when a watched file changes. I think that aligns nicely to create *wacth* versions of npm scripts:

```json
  // on package.json
  "lint": "eslint",
  "lint:watch": "nodemon ... --exec npm run lint",
```

I'm trying to do the same using `ts-node-dev`, but without success, yet. Is it possible?

EDIT 1

Following comments of @Trott, I realised my question could be clearer.

1. Why do you want to avoid adding `nodemon` as a dev-dependency?
   *Because I already use `ts-node-dev` to reload my application when I change my TS sources and it also works as a FS listener.*
2. What have you tried and what were the results? *I tried the following, below; I can setup `ts-node-dev` to run the linter, but I have to copy-and-paste the `lint` script into the end of the `lint:watch` script. It works, but I believe it's not the ideal and I hope there's a better way to do it.*

```json
  // real lines of my package.json
  "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.ts' --cache --cache-location out/.eslintcache",
  "lint:watch": "ts-node-dev --rs --debounce --transpile-only --respawn --inspect=7001 --watch './src/**/*.ts' -- node_modules/.bin/eslint './src/**/*.ts' --cache --cache-location out/.eslintcache",

  // what I "intended"
  "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.ts' --cache --cache-location out/.eslintcache",
  "lint:watch": "ts-node-dev --rs --debounce --transpile-only --respawn --inspect=7001 --watch './src/**/*.ts' --exec npm run lint ",
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid adding `nodemon` as a dev-dependency?

Comment: Also, what have you tried and what were the results?